# Indorse or Endorse?

Tags: word-usage, differences

When I was still working in the office, my Boss usually asks me to make an Indorsement/Endorsement. I used, the ENDORSEMENT, but I come to read my Professor's endorsement which is spelled as Indorsement. Well, I have this question long before, but I never mind searching for the correct word to use until now. Just five minutes ago, my Mom asked me to check her indorsement/endorsement and asked me to mail it to a her colleague. And, here I am today, battling with myself again.

Anyway, Cambridge Dictionary does not give meaning to the word [indorse](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/indorse) but rather give a link to  [endorse](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/endorse), which is fully defined by Cambridge.

Comment: There is such a word *indorse*? Why does my browser's spell-check get excited with that word? Synaudinous with *indoors*. No, *synaudinous* is not a word either. But now it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise **Indorse** is a valid word, and is documented as a variant of **Endorse**. Indorse seems to have been a used in older American formal documents.

This discussion of the [evolution of the two variants](http://www.yourdictionary.com/indorse) is quite interesting.

In business settings generally I recommend using the more common Endorse as I suspect many readers will consider Indorse to be an error. It is quite fun to use obscure words in personal correspondence, but in formal situations presentation is important - we need to appear to be correct. A possible exception to this, conceivably the "house style" is to use Indorse everywhere in technical documents, in which case we adopt that style.

Comment: But I see the word indorse commonly used in legal writing...?

Comment: @Pacerier in legal writing in which country? And what kind of legal writing? Text books? Formal contracts? I bow to your experience, I am guessing that this may well be an example of "house style", a particular profession, perhaps in a particular country uses the more specialised word. My suggestion of adopting the style of the "house" in which you work stands. I also recommend that when you leave the "house" you adapt to the more common usage.